Word file directly as a message in Outlook?
We are using an Exchange 2016 server on-premises. A user reported a strange email message in their mailbox: in Outlook 2016, it shows a Word icon in the message list. When I double-click it, instead of opening the message in its own Outlook window, it opens directly in Word. The "Reply" and "Forward" buttons don't work, and the message subject is a DOCX file name: Outlook screenshot
In the message list, it shows the sender as the same user who received it, but the user is sure they did not send it. In OWA, when I use the "View message details" function, it shows "No details were found for this message": OWA screenshot
What's worse, I cannot find it in the message tracking log.
How is it even possible to send such a message? I tried sending a Word document by using the "Send to Mail Recipient" function, but it shows as a normal message, just with the Word document as its body. After double-clicking, it opens in the Outlook window and I can see its email headers. Which logs could I check to see who sent that message and how?

It sounds like they dropped a Word document on the Inbox...

@GregAskew Tried that too, such action in Outlook causes opening "New message" window

Did you try it in clients other than Outlook?

@GregAskew I did try it in OWA without effect, but your question got me thinking and testing it more in Outlook. It turns out that only dragging files to the Inbox causes the "New message" window to appear. In other folders, the dragged file just lands in the folder and behaves exactly like in my user's case. I wasn't aware of this functionality.
Unfortunately, the "Microsoft Exchange Compliance Audit" service didn't start after the server restart, so I cannot verify who saved that Word file in the mail folder.

Your test results are correct. Dragging a file to your inbox will bring up the New Message window, which is a quick action to send a message. After dragging a file to a different folder(for example, a Sent Items), the file is not sent actually, so it cannot be viewed through the logs, which may just be a record of the action. I understand this as a misoperation. Although this did not pose any problems, it was distressing.

Here are some suggestions
1. Check Message Properties in Outlook: Right-click the email, select "Properties" or "Message Options."
2. Inspect in OWA: Check the raw message source if possible.
3. Verify Sender: Look for mailbox rules or spoofing.
4. Review Exchange Logs:
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Recipients "user@domain.com" -Start "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" -End "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"

5. Examine Transport Logs: Check TransportRoles\Logs on the server.
6. Investigate Junk Filtering: Check the user’s junk email settings.
7. Check for Add-ins: Ensure no add-ins/scripts are manipulating emails.
8. Analyze Event Logs: Look in Event Viewer under “Microsoft” -> “Exchange” -> “Transport” or “Mail Submission.”
9. Security Review: Audit for account compromise or unusual access logs.
10. Consult Microsoft Support: If unresolved, contact Microsoft for advanced help.
